# Validating type of array items in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, validation, bson

I am using MongoDB 4.0.

Documents in my collection can have a `numbers` field that holds an array of integers. We can validate that `numbers` is indeed an array by using the below code, but is it possible to make sure that they are integers?

```
properties: {
  numbers: {
    bsonType: 'array'
  }
 }
```

I have looked at the [validation docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) and the [BSON type docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) but nothing in either of those says anything about it. One example shows a field enclosed in square brackets (`["double"]`) but the type is not described as being an array and adding the brackets seems to have no effect.

Comment: The `["double"]` syntax indicates that more than one type might be appropriate. A type of `["double","string"]` would allow doubles and strings as valid types. I agree that this is confusing when dealing with the array type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be another attribute, `items`, where you define the scheme for the items in the array

```
properties: {
  numbers: {
    bsonType: 'array',
    items: {
      bsonType: 'int'
    }
  }
}
```

This attribute seems to [be from mongo 3.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/)

Comment: Does this actually work? I'm trying this syntax and the document won't validate unless the array is empty (which is valid). If I have [200,300] it's declared invalid...

Comment: Yeah, it does. but when using the mongo shell, ints have to be explicitly converted using NumberInt() because the shell defaults all numerics to double. The list of things I hate about mongo is growing.....

Answer (score -1):

You need a "`,`" character after '`array`', like this:

```
properties: {
  numbers: {
    bsonType: 'array' ,
    items: {
      bsonType: 'int'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see no difference between [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218339/3157428) and yours, please avoid answers with solution that was already proposed.

Comment: @Ruli He's not proposing a solution; he's saying the accepted answer needs a comma between the BSON entries to be syntactically valid. One of the quirks of Stack Overflow having higher reputation requirements for comments than answers. Flag as "not an answer" and the mods will take care of it.

Comment: Thx @Matt ! Yes think the comma change all, it's BISON syntax !

Comment: @Ruli next  time I can surround de comma like this **,**